# How to remove thousand separaters in number using javascript?

Tags: javascript

**problem:**

I want to remove the comma in a string and make it as a number.

It means,

- 234,345 should become 234345.
- 1,234 should become 1234
- 4,567,890 should become 4567890

I have created one code like this.

```
let a = "5,245"
function numberWithoutCommas(x) {
    return x.replace(",","");
}
const b = parseInt(numberWithoutCommas(a))
console.log(typeof(b))
console.log(b)
```

This is failing when there more comma in the string.It means 1,234,567 gives 1234. So can someone help me to achieve it?

Comment: `","`  =====> `/,/g`

Comment: From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): *If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting and joining should do the job
`return x.split(',').join('');`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply parse to a number and use a regex

```js
const s = ['5,332', '39,322,322,233']
function numberWithoutCommas(x) {
    return Number(x.replace(/,/g, ''));
}
for (const a of s) {
    const n = numberWithoutCommas(a);
    console.log(n, typeof n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

passing string as a first argument to replace method will only replace the very first occurrence.

```
let str = '111,11,11,1';
str.replace(',','') // result:- 11111,11,1
```

use regex instead

```
str.replace(/,/g,'') //result:- 11111111
```

in your use case

```
function numberWithoutCommas(x) {
    return x.replace(/,/g,"");
}
```

Comment: `replace` replaces all

Answer (score 0):

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a
> regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified
> values are replaced.
>
> Note: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression),
> only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all
> occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier.

So, to replace all the occurrences of `,`, we should rather use `/,/g` instead of just `,`.

Then your code would be something like the following

```
let a = "1,234,567"
function numberWithoutCommas(x) {
    return x.replace(/,/g,"");
}
const b = parseInt(numberWithoutCommas(a))
console.log(typeof(b))
console.log(b)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: `replace` replaces all